# Keep the order from the inner query Or Ordering the result based on the inner query data set

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySQL query like this -

```
SELECT u.id, u.email
FROM users 
WHERE u.email IN ('u2.gmail.com', 'u3@gmail.com', 'u1@gmail.com');
```

The output is like this -

```
| 5   |  u1@gmail.com  |
| 2   |  u2@gmail.com  |
| 1   |  u3@gmail.com  |
```

The output order is done based on the email address ascending. But I want to keep the order from the `IN` clause, ie -

```
| 2   | u2@gmail.com  |
| 1   | u3@gmail.com  |
| 5   | u1@gmail.com  |
```

I've already tried with `ORDER BY FIELD()` but it's not working. Can anyone help me how can I get this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi what inner subquery? Are you talking about the parameters in the `IN` clause?

Comment: @JorgeCampos, Yes you are right. thanks for your comment. I've just edited the question for clarification/readability

Comment: So that is not a subquery, it is only a list of parameters. I feel like that are little details on your question. The ordering you are seeking is unnatural, therefore you have make you parameters a subquery with ordering data so you can use it in your external query. Why you need this data in such particular sorting order? Maybe the answer you are seeking has a underlying different solution...

Comment: Have you tried FIND_IN_SET()? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set

Comment: see it here: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ubhmCRGBu1bJ6SndvEpKrU/0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code should work:

```
SELECT u.id, u.email
FROM users u
WHERE u.email IN ('u2@gmail.com', 'u3@gmail.com', 'u1@gmail.com')
ORDER BY field(u.email, 'u2@gmail.com', 'u3@gmail.com', 'u1@gmail.com')
```

If it does not work, provide a db/sql fiddle with sample data showing how it does not work.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ba7099c1a925124d82704a119eb2bda0) is a db<>fiddle showing that the above does work.

Note that this fixes typos in your query -- the "u2" in your `in` list and no `u` defined.

Answer (score 1):

Define the order that you want inside a `CTE` (for MySql 8.0+) and join to your table:

```
WITH cte(id, email) AS (
  SELECT 1, 'u2@gmail.com' UNION ALL 
  SELECT 2, 'u3@gmail.com' UNION ALL 
  SELECT 3, 'u1@gmail.com'
)
SELECT u.* 
FROM users u INNER JOIN cte c
ON c.email = u.email
ORDER BY c.id
```

This way there is no need to use the emails list twice in your code.
See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=dcfe64445d07e9a73eda94f7096b56c2).
Results:

```
> id | email       
> -: | :-----------
>  2 | u2@gmail.com
>  1 | u3@gmail.com
>  5 | u1@gmail.com
```